# Should answers that say something is unknown be accepted?

Tags: discussion

If you ask a question about a historical event and the only answer you receive is that it is unknown, should you mark this as the accepted answer, or should the question remain open, until (let us be really hopeful) a new source appears that answers the question (possibly in quite some time in the future... or maybe even never)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is in fact currently no scholarly consensus, then that is The Answer<sup>(TM)</sup> and it should be accepted.

If two years from now that changes, there's nothing stopping a new answer from being posted, or from the person asking the question to change their acceptance to the new answer.